# 07 honda fit stereo anti theft reset. Where is the 7?

Tags: honda, audio, security

Trying to reset stereo on 2007 Honda Fit after replacing battery. I have 2 security codes. The 1st didn't work, the 2nd code's 1st number is a 7. My stereo only has numbers 1-6. Are there other buttons that represent 7,8,9, and 0?

Answer (score 2):

Normally it works like this for radio codes

If your code is **4751**

- Press number 1 four times
- Press number 2 seven times
- Press number 3 five times
- Press number 4 one time

The code should then be accepted and the radio unlocked.

Comment: Your response is the most logical.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is in fact the security code? What you could have is the stereo's serial number. They are often listed in 2 blocks because that's how they are displayed on a car's information screen. There's no such thing as "2 security codes" for a car stereo.

Try retrieving the security code from [this site](https://radio-navicode.honda.com/) using either your VIN or the stereo's serial number (those 2 blocks of numbers you have, string them together).